# MySQL prepared statement - Uncaught ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, mysql

With the `db_doesUserExist` function, I am trying to check if a certain username exists in a mysql database. However when I try to run this function I get an error. The error indicates that I do not pass the right count of variables to the `bind_param` function, but I do.

I already checked if the `$username` variable is null and it is not.

Does anyone see my error or know what the problem might be? Thanks

```
function db_doesUserExist($link, $username) {
    $sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE username='?'";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
        $param_username = $username;
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_get_result($stmt);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $response = array(
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'result' => true
                );
            } else {
                $response = array(
                    'status' => 'success',
                    'result' => false
                );
            }
        } else{
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'error',
                'errorcode' => 1
            );
            http_response_code(500);
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    } else {
        $response = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'errorcode' => 1
        );
        http_response_code(500);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of variables must match the number of > parameters in the prepared statement in C:\path\to\file.php:17
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\path\to\file.php(1711): mysqli_stmt_bind_param(Object(mysqli_stmt), 's', NULL)
> #1 C:\path\to\file.php(929): db_doesUserExist(Object(mysqli), 'test')

Comment: Remove the `'` around the `'?'`, it has to be `WHERE username=?`. The `'` character is for strings, but you want a placeholder there.

Comment: That seemed to resolve part of the issue. Now I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_get_result()`

Comment: Because the function is called `mysqli_stmt_get_result`, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php.